# How do I get a QLabel to expand to full width?

Tags: c++, qt

I want a `QLabel` to expand to full width of the container regardless of the contents. (I want this because I dynamically set the text and add widgets later which cause it to cut off part of the text)

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setFixedSize(100,100);
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    this->setLayout(layout);
    QLabel *label = new QLabel;
    label->setStyleSheet("background-color:blue");
    label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, 
                         QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
    label->setText(tr("test"));
    layout->addWidget(label, 0, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);
}
```

This code shows that the blue box does not expand to the entire width, why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must set:

```
layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

By default every QWidget or QFrame add 15 pixels of margin in every direction.

The main problem is with setting the alignment when you add the widget to the layout. Use `label->setAlignment` instead.

```
layout->addWidget(label);
```

I compiled your code, it works with those changes.

Here is the minimal example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget* w = new QWidget;
    w->setFixedSize(100,100);
    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    w->setLayout(layout);
    QLabel* label = new QLabel;
    label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);
    label->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
    label->setStyleSheet("background-color:blue");
    label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding,
                     QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
    label->setText("test");
    layout->addWidget(label);
    w->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Edit should fix your problem now

Comment: Huh, you're right. It was the align that was causing the problem.

Comment: I just added the real fix, ty :)